# jQuery is mousedown on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mouseevent

I have a table where i want to change cell background on mouse over and mouse button down, my current solution doesn't work as I want it to :

```
function ChangeColor(sender) {

    sender.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

}

var clicking = false;


$(document).mouseup(function() {
    clicking = false;
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Table1 tr').each(function() {
        $('td', this).each(function() {
            $(this).mousedown(function() {
                clicking = true;
            });
            $(this).mousedown(function(event) {
                if (clicking==true) { ChangeColor(this); }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Is there any way to make it work like that ?

Comment: isnt mouse over and down on an element the same as click or am i missing something?

Comment: I don't rely understand what you're trying to say , mouseover!=click / mousedown=click

Comment: it is the combination i am confused about, if you mousedown whilst the mouse is over an element it fires the click event or are you after some kind of drag select?

Comment: yes , you can say I am trying to achieve some kind of drag select, like using paint tool pen while coloring pixels - does that make any sens ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I think it is what you're looking for.

Comment: @jacob mousedown!=click.  mousedown + mouseup = click

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**EDIT:** Given your comment above, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    isMouseDown = false

    $('body').mousedown(function() {
        isMouseDown = true;
    })
    .mouseup(function() {
        isMouseDown = false;
    });

    $('Table1 tr td').mouseenter(function() {
        if(isMouseDown)
            $(this).css({backgroundColor:'orange'});
    });
});
```

This will color the background of the `td` when you mouseover, but only if the mouse button is down.

---

Sounds like you just want to change the color when you click. If that's the case, it is much simpler than what you're attempting.

```
$(document).ready() {

    $('#Table1 tr td').click(function() {
        $(this).css({backgroundColor:'yellow'});
    });

});
```

This will change the background of the `td` elements yellow when you click them.

It will be similar to change the color when you mouseover.

**EDIT:** Just noticed the title of your question.

If you want to trigger a click when you hover...

```
$(document).ready() {

    $('#Table1 tr td').click(function() {
        $(this).css({backgroundColor:'yellow'});
    })
     .mouseenter(function() {
         $(this).click();
     });

});
```

...of course, you could eliminate the `click` in that case and just change the background with the `mouseenter` event.

Comment: that's freakin' genius patrick ! It does exactly what I would expect it to do. I've only added 'mousedown' for td to color single cell on single click as well. Thank you !